# What is the difference between these responses?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

Suppose I tell you that you can't understand what this means "fdhfshdgfjdsghskdrhgyc". You could reply "Yes, I can" or "No, I can". For the first phrase, it means that you are able to understand what that series of letters means and you are affirming your knowledge. The second phrase means that you are rejecting the idea that you can't understand it and are insisting that you can. These responses pretty much mean the same thing, correct?

Comment: We are making the assumption that you are very intelligent and know what that means, so don't mention it.

Comment: No, I can is unidiomatic.

Comment: The second one should be "No. I can." instead of "No, I can."

Comment: We use 'Yes' to contradict a negative statement.